# Reading a GUID Property from COM object with C++Builder

Tags: com, c++builder

I have a 3rd party COM object that I'm working with. Mostly fine, but I'm stuck on reading a GUID property from the object.

The relevant part of the auto-generated component wrappers/headers looks like this:

```
// *********************************************************************//
// DispIntf:  IFoo
// Flags:     (4416) Dual OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID:      {5DE5DAAF-5419-4B2B-9771-58EAEE780799}
// *********************************************************************//
template<class T>
class IFooDispT : public TAutoDriver<IFoo>
{
  ...
BSTR    __fastcall get_FileName(void);
HRESULT __fastcall get_ProjectGUID(/*AUTO_PARAM_ERROR(System::TGUID* Value)*/ VARIANT*  Value);
HRESULT __fastcall get_ProjectName(BSTR* Value/*[out,retval]*/);

__property   BSTR  FileName = {read = get_FileName};
__property   BSTR  ProjectName = {read = get_ProjectName};
```

Note how the `ProjectGUID` property is marked `AUTO_PARAM_ERROR`, and it doesn't appear in list of properties.

I've tried to read it directly via `get_ProjectGUID()` but it always returns `HRESULT = 0x80070057 (E_INVALID_ARGS)`.

The IDL of the dispinterface from OleView looks like this:-

```
[
  uuid(5DE5DAAF-5419-4B2B-9771-58EAEE780799),
  version(1.0),
  helpstring("Dispatch interface for xpCOMFoo Object"),
  dual
]
dispinterface IFoo {
    properties:
    methods:
 <...snipped...>
        [id(0x000000cf), propget]
        BSTR FileName();
        [id(0x000000d0), propget]
        GUID ProjectGUID();
        [id(0x000000d1), propget]
        BSTR ProjectName();
};
```

I've tested the same object from Delphi (although, not using the late bindings shown above) and I'm happy that the COM object itself is not at fault.

Comment: Can you show the relevant part of the TLB's IDL with OleView?

Comment: The COM object itself is at fault.  Methods of a *dispinterface* need to be callable with IDispatch::Invoke().  Which requires that the method's argument and return values can be stored in a VARIANT.  You can't store a GUID in a VARIANT.  It is not actually a dispinterface, it has the [dual] attribute.  You can only call the method early-bound.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling it like this:

```cpp
TAutoDriver<IFoo> foo;

// ...

GUID guid;
memset(&guid, 0, sizeof(guid));
// use -> to access the raw dual interface
HRESULT hr = foo->get_ProjectGUID(&guid);
```